# Function pointer for QVariant.toXXX function

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I don't know how to create a function pointer to a method in the Qt library that handles QVariant.  I have a number of places in my code where I convert a QVariantList to a QList where SomeType can be QString, int, QMap or other variables that can be held in the QVariant object.  At the time I'm going to use the method, the type is known.

Can I write a method using templates?  Below is the pseudo code of the method I'd like to write

```
template <class T>
QList<T> QVariantListToQList(QVariantList qvList, (* QVariant::toXXX()) convert)
{
    QList<T> qlistOfMembers;
    foreach(T listMember, qvList)
    {
        qlist.OfMember.append(listMmeber.convert());
    }
    return qlistOfMembers;
}
```

A link to the documentation where this is discussed or a method using the correct syntax would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Use [`qvariant_cast`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#qvariant_cast) or the [`QVariant::value`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#value) functions, and drop that parameter altogether.

Something like:

```
template <class T>
QList<T> QVariantListToQList(QVariantList const& qvList)
{
    QList<T> qlistOfMembers;
    foreach(QVariant const& listMember, qvList)
    {
        qlistOfMembers.append(listMember.value<T>());
    }
    return qlistOfMembers;
}
```

If you want to do it your way, the syntax gets a bit tricky:

```
#include <QtCore>

template <class T>
QList<T> QVariantListToQList(QVariantList const& qvList, 
                             T (QVariant::*convert)() const)
{
    QList<T> qlistOfMembers;
    foreach(QVariant const& listMember, qvList)
    {
        qlistOfMembers.append((listMember.*convert)());
    }
    return qlistOfMembers;
}

int main(void)
{
    QVariantList vl;
    vl.append(QVariant(QString("hello")));
    qDebug() << vl;
    QList<QString> sl = QVariantListToQList<QString>(vl, &QVariant::toString);
    qDebug() << sl;
}
```

Comment: The first function is exactly what I needed.  The second function is exactly what I asked for.  Thanks

Comment: A follow-up question has been posted.  [so link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096292/c-function-pointer-used-to-convert-a-qvariant-to-a-custom-type).  (If the QVariant is a QVariantMap and I have a conversion function to convert the QVariantMap into MyClass, can I pass a function pointer to do the work?)