# c++ function pointer used to convert a QVariant to {a custom type

Tags: c++, qt, templates

A QVariant is holding a QMap object that is to be converted into a custom type, MyClass or MyClass2.

Example:

```
class MyClass{
   int item1;
   int item2;
   QString string1;
   AnotherClass subclass;
};

class MyClass2{
   int item1;
   QString string1;
   AnotherClass subclass;
};
```

functions have been written to convert the QVariant to the associated classes

```
MyClass QVariantToMyClass1(QVariant);
MyClass2 QVariantToMyClass1(QVariant);
```

My question is, in a template function what is the proper way to pass in the function pointer?  The code shown below returns an error 'const class QVariant has no member named convFunct'

```
template<class T>
QList<T> QVariantToQList(QVariant & qv,T (* convFunct)() )
{
    // Create the list that will hold the return values
    QList<T> qListOfMembers;
    if(qv.typeName() == "QVariantMap"){
        foreach(QVariant const& mapMember,qv.toMap())
        {
            qListOfMembers.append(mapMember.convFunct());
        }
    }
    else if (qv.typeName() == "QVariantList"){
        foreach(QVariant const& listMember,qv.toList())
        {
            qListOfMembers.append(listMember.convFunct());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<< "QVariantToQList currently is implemented only for QMap and QList types";
        throw ;
    }
    return qListOfMembers;
}
```

This is a [follow-up question to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087966/function-pointer-for-qvariant-toxxx-function)  The difference between that question and this one is the T is 'MyClass' or 'MyClass2' instead of a type that is normally held by a QVariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `convFunct` supposed to be a function that get a `QVariant` and return an instance of `MyClass` or `MyClass2`, is it correct? if your answer is yes, then this function should get a parameter of type `QVariant` and your function get no parameter, so the result is:

```
template<class T>
QList<T> QVariantToQList(QVariant & qv,T (*convFunct)(QVariant const&) )
{
    // Create the list that will hold the return values
    QList<T> qListOfMembers;
    if(qv.typeName() == "QVariantMap"){
        foreach(QVariant const& mapMember,qv.toMap())
        {
            qListOfMembers.append(convFunct(mapMember));
        }
    }
    else if (qv.typeName() == "QVariantList"){
        foreach(QVariant const& listMember,qv.toList())
        {
            qListOfMembers.append(convFunct(listMember));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<< "QVariantToQList currently is implemented only for QMap and QList types";
        throw ;
    }
    return qListOfMembers;
}
```

Comment: you interpreted the question correctly.  I made the suggested changes, but the compiler continues to complain 'error: 'const class QVariant' has no member named 'convFunct'

Comment: @DarwinIcesurfer Do you copy the code or just convert your function prototype, look where function used in my code and let me know the result

Comment: I tried to modify my code in place rather than doing a cut-and-paste.  When I cut and pasted your code it worked fine.  Thanks, answer accepted and +1 to comment.